# How to host website on github with HTML and CSS preprocessor format?

Tags: html, github, pug, preprocessor, postcss

I have created a new repository and and included all files necessary to host a website on github, see (https://github.com/tonystaark/tonystaark.github.io/tree/master)

However, I received a 404 error when I visited my own website at tonystaark.github.io. The error says that 'For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file.'

How do I convert my .pug format into a html (or .postcss into a .css) file then?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily generate html from pug file using command line option,

```
pug -O '{"doctype": "html"}' index.pug
```

It's automatically generate index.html file for you.You can check other options from [here](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-cli/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Thanks. But do you know where should I insert the command line? Is it into my pug file? Sorry I am a newbie.

Comment: If you use unix or linux operating system open your terminal for go to folder that include index.pug file and run command . If you use windows , you can do same thing from npm. If you don't have pug on npm , you can check how to download it from [here](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-cli/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: The user is talking about how to do this with GitHub pages. They do not allow users to have access to the command line in order to do something like you are suggesting.

Comment: For host your Github repository , you must have index.html file in repository.  He can generate pug file to html on local. After that he can update his repository and publish.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. There is no way to do that automatically, though, which is what it sounds like he wants. GitHub pages does not allow for that.

Answer (score 0):

Pug files need to be compiled onto the server before being served as an HTML file. There aren't many great ways to compile Pug in the client. If you have a strong need to use Pug as a templating engine, GitHub Pages will not be able to do that. You will need to host your site somewhere that supports Node.js engines (Heroku, DigitalOcean, Amazon S3, etc.)

I didn't see any Pug files in your GitHub repo, though, so I don't know if you figured out another solution or tried to do something else.